# Webmatrix - upgraded, now cannot browse localhost sites

Tags: asp.net, http, firefox, localhost, webmatrix

I am in the process of developing an ASP.NET site. Yesterday it was working fine. I then upgraded WebMatrix as I keep getting pop ups.

Now, when I try to browse to my site all I am getting is the website text, no CSS, no functionality just plain html text.

No links are working but when I try to enter something into the search bar and hit enter I get the following:

> Firefox doesn't know how to open this address, because the protocol
>   (localhost) isn't associated with any program.
>
> ```
> You might need to install other software to open this address.
> ```

Now I investigated this and found a this topic:
[IIS, IE does not recognize web page protocal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11316682/iis-ie-does-not-recognize-web-page-protocal/14432847#14432847)

And yes when I added the http and copied the address into IE it brought up the correct page. However then when I tried to navigate around I got the same problem in IE with the message:

> No apps are installed to open this type of file (localhost)

I'm totally baffled so any advice would be really appreciated.